# Parsing form data in azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, body-parser

I have a small testing a nodejs web app on azure that uses an azure cosmos db to insert and retrieve data. The web app is based on express framework, mongoose (for database interaction), pug for templates and body-parser for parsing the data send by a web form.

The problem I have encountered is that I cannot access the data send by the web form, based on which I want to insert a new document in the azure cosmos db. Basically when I submit the web form the app should access the form data (with the help of *body-parser* module), create a new document in the database and refresh the view (which will contain the info from the newly created document).

Below is the code of this small app.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5050; //normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '5050');
app.set('port', port);
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://[user].documents.azure.com:10255/testdb?ssl=true`, {
    auth: {
      user: `[username]`,
      password: `[password]`
    }
  })
  .then(() => console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

let citySchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    id: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    country: {type: String, required: true}
});

const Cities = mongoose.model('Cities', citySchema);

let getData = function(request, response) {
    Cities.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { return "There was an error";}
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        response.render('index', {
            panelTitle: "Azure CosmosDB Test",  
            panelBody:"Testing how to access Azure ComsosDB",
            cities: data
        });
    });
};

let urlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    getData(request, response);
});

app.get('/error', function(request, response) {
    response.render('error');
})

app.post('/', urlencoded, function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body);
    let newCity = new Cities({id: request.body.id, name: request.body.name, 
       country: request.body.country});
    console.log(newCity);
    newCity.save(function(err, savedCity){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(savedCity));
    });

    response.redirect('back');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

On localhost the code work just fine, it insert the new document in the database and then in the refreshed view the new city appears on the list (generated based on the pug file).

---

However on Azure nothing happened. The view is refreshed but the new document is not created and of course the view does not contain the info send by the web form. It is not a problem with the database connection because the app is able to extract the information for generating the list of the cities. Furthermore if in the *post* route, when I am creating a new city and try to save it I use direct values like this:

```
let newCity = new Cities({id: 'MUN", name: "Munich", 
       country: "Germany"});
```

the document is created and saved in the azure cosmos db and the view contains the new data.

It seems to me that the **req.body** is empty and form data is not parsed although I am using the *body-parser* module in this respect. In the browser on developer tools - network tab - is showing the form data send to the server and i have a status code of 302.

If you have any idea why this is not working on azure please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: If my suggestion works, you cloud accept it. If not, feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: I am testing this week-end and I will let you know.

Comment: It is working now! Thank you! My impression from perusing the the body-parse examples in the docs was that bodyParser.json() and bodyParser.urlencoded() should be used independently and not together..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have used statement `app.use(bodyParser.json());`
to make your json data recognized by the bodyParser.

Without it, I get same empty result `{}` as yours.

BodyParser can't tell the incoming body format unless we specify it.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why on localhost is working without using _app.use(bodyParser.json())_? Thanks!

Comment: @LucianTanase No idea...On my side, it doesn't work either on localhost if miss the statement. Maybe you can check node version. My node is v8.11.1.